# Organize keyword in LOAD/AS Pig script

Tags: load, apache-pig, field

I'm moving my first steps with PIG.

```
rawdata = load 'path' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',') AS (...);
```

Following the AS I have a long list of fields, is there a way to organize them in a smart way ?

I tried to store the fields in a variable and then pass it to the AS but it doesn't work.

Giving a look to the documentation: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#load

I haven't found the solution, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

No way around it.Either specify the fields or use positional notation along with cast.

If you don't specify the data fields after 'AS',Pig automatically defaults the datatype for each field as bytearray.You will then have to cast the fields.You can also access the fields using positional notation i.e. $0,$1,$2 etc.